# use SSH over Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

How do I run this SSH on a python script?

```
ssh gateway@192.168.0.189 'DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "Title" "Description"'
```

My python script will ask for a raw_input() for the `Title`, and another one for the `Description`. Then the python will run the SSH inserting the `Title` and `Description` typed by the user.

Comment: Take a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/).

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(
    '''ssh gateway@192.168.0.189 'DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "{0}" "{1}"' '''.format(title, description),
    shell=True)
```

Comment: And don't forget to properly escape your input if it comes from the user :)

Comment: How do I properly escape the input? I mean it keeps getting error when using apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to want a little more control, you should also check out the paramiko library: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko It's an SSH2 library for python.